# How to charge existing customers for a products?

Tags: stripe-payments

If you know Audible, that's how my service works. You can have subscriptions which you get credits for but you can also just buy single items right away (if you want).

Subscriptions work for me but what I can't get my head around is how I can charge an existing customer, using his default payment method, on a single item. Let's stick to Audible.

A user wants to buy a single audio-track.

I though I can:

1. Create a `Product` for this track (setting a name and an image-url)
2. Create or re-use a `Price` and set the charge-amount as stated in my database
3. Somehow create an [`Invoice`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object) or `Charge` for this `Price`/`Product` and move one

However, I just don't quite get how to do that.

Looking at the docs of [`Invoice`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object), it appears to me that I am not able to add a single product or price and let Stripe automatically charge the customer.

I thought it would look something like this:

```java
public void buyProduct(String productId, Customer customer) {

    InvoiceCreateParams.builder()
            .setCustomer(customer.getId())
            .setDefaultPaymentMethod(customer.getPaymentMethod())
            .setAutoAdvance(true)
            .setCollectionMethod(CollectionMethod.CHARGE_AUTOMATICALLY)
            // Add product/price here ?
            .build();

    // ...
}
```

So, what is the simplest way to charge a customer for a product?

#### Update

I noticed that an `InvoiceItem` can take a `Invoice` ID.

Is the following correct (in principal)?

Setting `autoAdvance` to `true` and `CHARGE_AUTOMATICALLY` as collection-method, will the user charged correctly as I intend to using the code below?

```java
public void createInvoice() throws StripeException {
    
    String customerId = null;
    String paymentMethodId = null;
    String priceId = null;
    boolean chargeAutomatically = true;

    InvoiceCreateParams invoiceCreateParams = InvoiceCreateParams.builder()
            .setCustomer(customerId)
            .setDefaultPaymentMethod(paymentMethodId)
            .setAutoAdvance(chargeAutomatically)
            .setCollectionMethod(CollectionMethod.CHARGE_AUTOMATICALLY)
            .build();

    Invoice invoice = Invoice.create(invoiceCreateParams);

    InvoiceItemCreateParams invoiceItemCreateParams = InvoiceItemCreateParams.builder()
            .setCustomer(customerId)
            .setPrice(priceId)
            .setInvoice(invoice.getId())
            .build();

    InvoiceItem invoiceItem = InvoiceItem.create(invoiceItemCreateParams);
    
}
```

It feels weird to create an invoice at first, and set everything up for charging a customer immediatelly, and only *after* having done so, set the actual item that the user wants to buy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at this: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/invoices/sending#one-off

First, you'll want to create an Invoice Item using the Price and Customer ID (no need to create the invoice first). You can create as many Invoice Items as you want, depending on how many things you want to charge your customer for. Then you can create an Invoice which will automatically pick up all the pending Invoice Items for a given Customer.